# Why can't Turner Syndrome occur in males?

Tags: genetics

In Turner Syndrome, one X chromosome is missing, meaning that the resulting egg or sperm has 22 chromosomes (without pair) and the 23rd chromosome is missing.  If this develops in an egg, and a normal sperm carrying a Y chromosome fertilizes that egg, then due to presence of a Y chromosome, can a male with Turner Syndrome develop?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking.  What is the chromosomal makeup of this proposed individual?

Answer (score 5):

Because it is not viable to not have any X chromosome ([non-peer reviewed reference](http://education.seattlepi.com/can-zygote-survive-x-sex-chromosome-4599.html)).

The X chromosome is much bigger than the Y chromosome and carry a lot of essential genes (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_chromosome#Gene_list)). A zygote just does not appear to be viable without X chromosome.

Comment: Why the tag markup for X and Y?

Comment: @arboviral clarity, I assume.

Comment: Tag mark removed. I did that in the past already. I suppose, it once was handy to not confound chromosome names with variables, with locus names or allele names.

Comment: I can't get it into my head and can't imagine it properly .Firstly ,if there is an egg containing 22 chromosomes with one chromosome missing and that is an x chromosome but an egg contributes only one x to zygote and other x or y comes from father  So,Can't that female contribute its other x chromosome to zygote as it has two x chromosomes?

Comment: @RabikJohn After production of the egg, there is no way for the female organism to "do" something about the chromosomes. If the egg or sperm was incorrectly built, the zygote develops as far as it can. And in case of no X chromosome that is not very far. Maybe you can read more about egg and sperm production processes to fully understand.

Comment: I think it maybe like that, egg has one missing chromosome which is an x one and if that egg is fertilized by a y chromosome carrying sperm, then there would be no further development of male because as remi has mentioned that without x chromosome  further development cannot takes place so essentially it would be a female with only one x chromosome and no male with turner syndrome develops